# Package Does Not Exist - JAVA

Tags: java, package

I have 3 classes:

TestPackages.java in c:\ws

```
package p1;
import p2.C;

public class TestPackages
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    A a = new A();
    a.print();
    C c = new C();
 }
}
```

A.java in c:\ws

```
package p1;
public class A
{
public A(){

}
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Dziala");
}

}
```

C.java in c:\ws2

```
package p2;

public class C
{
public C()
{
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println("class C");
}
}
```

Compiled classes:

c:\ws\p1\A.class

c:\ws2\p2\C.class

When I set my classpath:

set classpath = c:\ws;c:\ws2

then go to c:\ws and compile:

javac -d . TestPackages.java

I get error: "package p2 does not exist"

Comment: You need to study the concept of packages and how to access them in classpath. This link should be useful to you  ---- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Still I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the classpath alright. Just change the following

```
javac -d . TestPackages.java
```

to following (when you are in c:\ws folder)

```
javac -d . p1\TestPackages.java
```

To add to my earlier comment, this has been explained in [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)